# Upgrading to Laravel 5.1 AWS SDK not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, aws-sdk

I updated composer.json with the following line:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0"
```

Ran composer update, then updated my config/app.php file:

```
'providers' => [
    Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class,

'aliases' => [
    'AWS'       => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class,
```

I'm trying to call the AWS S3 Bucket like so(worked in L4.2):

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');
```

I'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SDK package for Laravel. It will install AWS library as one of its dependencies:

```
{
  "require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"
  }
}
```

Have a look at the official docs here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

Comment: Key and secret need to be updated in the config laravel generates using php artisan vendor:publish.         'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',''),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',''),

Comment: Is Laravel 5.1 compatible with aws-sdk V2?